# DAX: Circular dependency in calculation column in Dimension Unique Key

Tags: powerbi, dax

I try to add a calculated column in my DIM Calendar that simply returns a 1 if the date is equal to the maximum date for which data is found in the table FACT. This means I expect only a single 1 in the entire table, since the Date column in DIM Calendar is unique and only 1 date from table FACT will be the maximum.

I try this using the following DAX:

```
Max_Date_Fact = 
VAR _DateKey = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX('FACT'[%DateKey])
    ,FILTER('FACT', SUM('FACT'[Amount]) > 0 )
    ,ALL('DIM Calendar') --With or without this, no difference.
)
RETURN
IF('DIM Calendar'[%DateKey] = _DateKey, 1, 0)
```

However this gives me an error because a circular dependency was detected.
The only solution I found doesn't apply to my situation `(using ALL, ALLEXCEPT(KeyColumn), REMOVEFILTERS(OtherCalcColumns))`, since this is my only calculated column and since my DIM Calendar table has a unique key on column [%DateKey], and is also marked as the Primary key of the table. It has a unidirectional relationship with FACT via column [%DateKey].

I notice that as soon as I try to add a measure within the FILTER() statement, I receive the circular dependency error. Any workaround to this?

Comment: Can you share a sample .pbix with the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot, this is a DirectQuery model. Probably good to add: I try to add this calculated column to the DIM Calendar table, not in the main model, but in the composite model.